# How can I dynamically add a post to a custom post type which uses a custom field?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type called "patients". I was using only the post title, but now I need to make a relationship with users.

I made this by creating a custom post field (created by ACF), a relational field showing a type of user. It works nice for the admin, but I also need to insert some posts dynamically. How can I do that?

I added posts (before the need of the relationship) using this:

```
wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'post_name'  => $p_name,
        'post_title' => $p_name,
        'post_type'  => 'patient'
    ), 
    true 
);
```

Comment: You would have to insert post using `wp_insert_post` function. This function returns the new post ID. Use this ID to add meta fields for the post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sur but I think you had (will probalby help other people as the guy who I was 1hour ago)/have same problem that I just resolve.

You have a custom field and you want to manage an User type field in it ?!

Well, everyone know UPDATE_FIELD, but what I didn't know that if you want to add a user, u just have to give the ID, and not the array structure taht print out when u get this fild (nickname, nicename, displayname...)

update_field('yourfieldkey',  arrayofyouruserID,  theidofyourrelatedpost);

My code to manage (add/delete) new user in relation with the post :

```
/* remake the memberassigned list*/
$ticket_users = get_field('tickets_assignedto', $thispost_id);
$new_assignedmembersID = array();
if ( $ticket_users != '' ) {
   foreach ($ticket_users as $ticket_user) {
       if ( $ticket_user['ID'] != $member_id ) {
            $new_assignedmembersID[] = $ticket_user['ID'];
       } 
   }
}

if ( $byeorhi == 'member_unassigned') {
    $new_assignedmembersID[] = $member_id;
}

update_field('field_54b8d8b213289',  $new_assignedmembersID,  $thispost_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments by @Nilambar, `wp_insert_post` returns the `ID` of the post it created.  So:

```
$new_patient = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'post_name'  => $p_name,
        'post_title' => $p_name,
        'post_type'  => 'patient'
    ), 
    true 
);
```

Then used the returned `ID` to create your relationships, add your meta and terms, etc.

Comment: I already know `wp_insert_post` returns the new created post ID. My problem is how to replicate the functioning of my form which uses a custom post field.